Object attribute reference causes SIGSEGV
/******************************************************************************

Welcome to GDB Online.
GDB online is an online compiler and debugger tool for C, C++, Python, Java, PHP, Ruby, Perl,
C#, OCaml, VB, Swift, Pascal, Fortran, Haskell, Objective-C, Assembly, HTML, CSS, JS, SQLite, Prolog.
Code, Compile, Run and Debug online from anywhere in world.

*******************************************************************************/
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
class Okret {
public:
    string nazwa;
    int id, moc, szybkosc, zaloga, celnosc, hp;
    Okret(int identifier, string name, int power, int speed, int crew, int accuracy, int hitpoints) {
        nazwa = name;
        moc = power;
        szybkosc = speed;
        zaloga = crew;
        celnosc = accuracy;
        id = identifier;
        hp = hitpoints;
    }
    Okret() {}
    void get() {
        cout << "***************\nID: " << id << "\nNAZWA: " << nazwa << "\nMOC : " << moc << "\nSZYBKOSC: " << szybkosc << "\nHP: " << hp << "\nZALOGA: " << zaloga << "\nCELNOSC: " << celnosc << "\n\n";
    }
};
class Krazownik : public Okret {
public:
    int iloscDzial, zasieg;
    Krazownik(int identifier, string name, int power, int speed, int crew, int accuracy, int hitpoints, int cannonCount, int range) : Okret(identifier, name, power, speed, crew, accuracy, hitpoints) {
        iloscDzial = cannonCount;
        zasieg = range;
    }
    Krazownik() {}
    void get() {
        Okret::get();
        cout << "ILOSC DZIAL: " << iloscDzial << "\nZASIEG: " << zasieg << "\n\n";
    }
};
class LodzPodwodna : public Krazownik {
public:
    int glebokosc;
    bool czyAtom;
    LodzPodwodna(int identifier, string name, int power, int speed, int crew, int accuracy, int hitpoints, int cannonCount, int range, int depth, bool isAtomic) : Krazownik(identifier, name, power, speed, crew, accuracy, hitpoints, cannonCount, range) {
        glebokosc = depth;
        czyAtom = isAtomic;
    }
    LodzPodwodna() {}
    void get() {
        Krazownik::get();
        cout << "GLEBOKOSC: " << glebokosc << "\nATOM: " << czyAtom << "\n\n";
    }
};
class Flota {
public:
    Okret** okrety;
    Krazownik** krazowniki;
    LodzPodwodna** lpodwodne;
    int identifier = 0;
    int ships[3];
    Flota(int iloscOkretow, int iloscKrazownikow, int iloscLodziPodwodnych) {
        ships[0] = iloscOkretow;
        ships[1] = iloscKrazownikow;
        ships[2] = iloscLodziPodwodnych;
        okrety = new Okret * [ships[0]];
        krazowniki = new Krazownik * [ships[1]];
        lpodwodne = new LodzPodwodna * [ships[2]];
        string name[2][10] = { {"HMS", "LA", "OZM", "ZLB", "SHW", "CHM", "KTR", "RJ45", "FFK", "REP"}, {"Danietz", "Magda", "Patrycja", "MOSiR", "JTFolio", "Pandziak", "Morcinek", "Fentanyl", "Robercia", "Malpa"} }, typy[3] = { "Okrety:", "Krazowniki:", "Lodzie podw.:" };
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < ships[i]; j++) {
                string tname = name[0][rand() % 10] + ' ' + name[1][rand() % 10];
                switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    okrety[j] = new Okret(identifier, tname, rand() % 11 + 15, rand() % 201 + 200, rand() % 4 + 1, rand() % 16 + 60, rand() % 100 + 300);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    krazowniki[j] = new Krazownik(identifier, tname, rand() % 21 + 40, rand() % 176 + 200, rand() % 21 + 10, rand() % 31 + 45, rand() % 500 + 750, rand() % 3 + 1, rand() % 76 + 75);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    lpodwodne[j] = new LodzPodwodna(identifier, tname, rand() % 11 + 35, rand() % 301 + 150, rand() % 3 + 2, rand() % 11 + 75, rand() % 250 + 600, 2, rand() % 101 + 150, rand() % 301 + 150, (rand() % 2 == 0) ? true : false);
                    break;
                }
                identifier++;
            }
        cout << "=== FLOTA ===\nOkretow: " << iloscOkretow << "\nKrazownikow: " << iloscKrazownikow << "\nLodzi podwodnych: " << iloscLodziPodwodnych << "\n=============\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < ships[0]; i++)
            okrety[i]->get();
        for (int i = 0; i < ships[1]; i++)
            krazowniki[i]->get();
        for (int i = 0; i < ships[2]; i++)
            lpodwodne[i]->get();
    }
};
bool checkVictory(int hp1, int hp2, string nazwa1, string nazwa2, int id1, int id2) {
    if (hp1 <= 0 && hp2 <= 0) {
        cout << "[REMIS] Oba '" << nazwa1 << "' oraz '" << nazwa2 << "' leza na dnie basenu! (OVERKILL: " << hp1 << " hp i " << hp2 << " hp)!\n";
        return true;
    }
    if (hp1 <= 0) {
        cout << "[WYGRANA] '" << nazwa2 << " " << id2 << "' zwyciezyl '" << nazwa1 << " " << id2 << "' (OVERKILL: " << hp1 << " hp)!\n";
        return true;
    }
    if (hp2 <= 0) {
        cout << "[WYGRANA] '" << nazwa1 << " " << id1 << "' zwyciezyl '" << nazwa2 << " " << id1 << "' (OVERKILL: " << hp2 << " hp)!\n";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int rem(LodzPodwodna* statek1, LodzPodwodna* statek2) {
    LodzPodwodna* statek[2] = { statek1, statek2 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (rand() % 101 <= statek[0 + i]->celnosc) {
            statek[1 - i]->hp -= statek[0 + i]->moc * statek[0 + i]->iloscDzial - statek[1 - i]->glebokosc / 30;
            cout << "'" << statek[0 + i]->nazwa << " " << statek[0 + i]->id << "' godzi '" << statek[1 - i]->nazwa << "' (" << statek[0 + i]->moc * statek[0 + i]->iloscDzial - statek[1 - i]->glebokosc / 30 << " hp)! ";
            if (statek[1 - i]->hp > 0)
                cout << "Pozostalo " << statek[1 - i]->hp << " hp.";
            else if (statek[1 - i]->czyAtom) {
                cout << "\n[BOMBA] Awaryjna orpeda atomowa zostala wystrzelona! ";
                if (rand() % 101 < 13) {
                    statek[0 + i]->hp -= 9999;
                    cout << "Niezneutralizowana na czas, obraca cel w proch!";
                }
                else
                    cout << "Nie trafia!";
            }
            cout << "\n";
            if (checkVictory(statek[0]->hp, statek[1]->hp, statek[0]->nazwa, statek[1]->nazwa, statek[0]->id, statek[1]->id))
                return 0;
        }
        else
            cout << "'" << statek[0 + i]->nazwa << "' chybił!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
void walka(Flota* flota1, Flota* flota2) {
    char dummy;
    while (1) {
        cout << "Oczekiwanie...\n>> ";
        cin >> dummy;
        Flota* args[2] = { flota1, flota2 };
        int total = flota1->ships[0] + flota1->ships[1] + flota1->ships[2], tura = 1;
        vector<vector<LodzPodwodna*>> floty(2, vector<LodzPodwodna*>(total));
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < args[i]->ships[0]; j++) {
                Okret* okret = args[i]->okrety[j];
                floty[i][j] = new LodzPodwodna(okret->id, okret->nazwa, okret->moc, okret->celnosc, okret->zaloga, okret->celnosc, okret->hp, 1, 130, 1, false);
                floty[i][j]->get();
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < args[i]->ships[1]; j++) {
                Krazownik* krazownik = args[i]->krazowniki[j];
                floty[i][j] = new LodzPodwodna(krazownik->id, krazownik->nazwa, krazownik->moc, krazownik->celnosc, krazownik->zaloga, krazownik->celnosc, krazownik->hp, krazownik->iloscDzial, krazownik->zasieg, 1, false);
                floty[i][j]->get();
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < args[i]->ships[2]; j++)
                floty[i][j] = args[i]->lpodwodne[j];
        cout << "\n######################\n        WALKA\n######################\n";
        bool hasEnded = false;
        while (!hasEnded) {
            hasEnded = true;
            cout << "\n--- TURA " << tura;
            for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                cout << "\n";
                if (checkVictory(floty[0][i]->hp, floty[1][i]->hp, floty[0][i]->nazwa, floty[1][i]->nazwa, floty[0][i]->id, floty[1][i]->id))
                    continue;
                if (floty[0][i]->szybkosc >= floty[1][i]->szybkosc)
                    rem(floty[0][i], floty[1][i]);
                else
                    rem(floty[1][i], floty[0][i]);
                hasEnded = false;
            }
            tura++;
        }
        cout << "\n--- KONIEC\n\n";
    }
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int input[3] = { 1, 1, 0 };
    
    Flota flota1(input[0], input[1], input[2]);
    Flota flota2(input[0], input[1], input[2]);
    walka(&flota1, &flota2);
    return 0;
}

Hello,
The aforementioned is my naval war simulator. It operates on 3 integers given at start, each defining the amount of the respective ship class participating (all belong to the mother Flota class). The differences between them are stats, some appearing in subsequent child classes only (they are inherited if possible).
Skipping class presentation by for get(), another Flota object is generated, with equal number of contained objects.
Then the simulation begins. Each object interacts with another one hosted in the opposite array element.
However, when at least 2 kinds of ships are present, SIGSEGV occurs when check victory() function is called with parameters being references to object data.
Why is that? Calling the attributes themselves causes the error, endemic to walka() function.
Please, help
EDIT: In order to replicate, in the first input use, for example, 1 1 0, and input anything in the next one (the val doesn't matter).
EDIT 2: Fixed the user input to the aforementioned combination.

Just remove cin >> input[0] >> input[1] >> input[2]; and simply pass the arguments that are needed to reproduce the issue.

Did you debug your app? Looking at the call stack might help you find out where the issue is

Use a debugger to catch the crash, and see where and when in your code it happens.

Note that the Krazownik class doesn't initialize the parent Okret class with all its arguments.

Here address sanitizer points to:
/app/example.cpp:163:33: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct LodzPodwodna'
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000020 (pc 0x000000407190 bp 0x7ffe87ac63e0 sp 0x7ffe87ac6160 T0)
==1==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==1==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x407190 in walka(Flota*, Flota*) /app/example.cpp:163
    #1 0x408740 in main /app/example.cpp:184
    #2 0x7fe283629d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: c289da5071a3399de893d2af81d6a30c62646e1e)
    #3 0x7fe283629e3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f) (BuildId: c289da5071a3399de893d2af81d6a30c62646e1e)
    #4 0x403394 in _start (/app/output.s+0x403394) (BuildId: 671a5091a9969ac5e5067d77bcefc6c3ca93cbb5)

Now example.cpp:163 is this line:
if (checkVictory(floty[0][i]->hp, floty[1][i]->hp, floty[0][i]->nazwa, floty[1][i]->nazwa, floty[0][i]->id, floty[1][i]->id))

Based on code above range of indexes for floty is correct:
vector<vector<LodzPodwodna*>> floty(2, vector<LodzPodwodna*>(total));

So problem must be pointers itself.
This part of code is fishy:
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < args[i]->ships[0]; j++) {
                Okret* okret = args[i]->okrety[j];
                floty[i][j] = new LodzPodwodna(okret->id, okret->nazwa, okret->moc, okret->celnosc, okret->zaloga, okret->celnosc, okret->hp, 1, 130, 1, false);
                floty[i][j]->get();
            }

Note that range of indexes j is not same as in place of failure nad palce of initialization of floty. There it depends on total value and in problematic code it depends on args[i]->ships[0].
Note relation between those:
int total = flota1->ships[0] + flota1->ships[1] + flota1->ships[2];

So total is always larger from one of flota1->ships[0] flota1->ships[1]!
SO bottom line you are dereferencing nullptr since total value is inconsistent with floty initialization.

Quick run with valgrind tells me that you have an invalid read here
if (checkVictory(floty[0][i]->hp, floty[1][i]->hp, floty[0][i]->nazwa, floty[1][i]->nazwa, floty[0][i]->id, floty[1][i]->id))

and indeed you can verify that elements floty[0][1] and floty[1][1] are nullptr.
But the root-cause of this bug is that you are using raw pointers and manual memory management

The fault lies in the initialization for loops not having starting j value equal to the amount of occupied slots + 1. The snippet inputs objects in the table from 0, therefore the result for the input combination 1 1 0 would cause the table to have 1 object present only (one would be overwritten according to the explanation above).
